# Where is the completed scenario data stored for RollerCoaster Tycoon: Deluxe?

Tags: steam, windows, gog, rollercoaster-tycoon

I'm hoping the Stack Exchange community can give a definitive answer on this. I recently purchased a new computer, and I'm attempting to migrate a bunch of game save files to it. I've managed to get all of my games situated except for RollerCoaster Tycoon: Deluxe. The saved games are stored at the following location in the Steam version:

`..\steamapps\common\RollerCoaster Tycoon Deluxe\Saved Games`

After installing the game on my new computer, I transferred the files from the above directory to the same location on my new computer. However, when I load the game, it does not show my completed scenarios. For example, when clicking the "Start New Game" button from the main menu, the "Select Scenario for New Game" window opens. In that window, none of the scenarios show that they have been completed. The window loads as if this is a brand new installation, with no saved data. Here is a screenshot showing as such:

[image: RollerCoasterTycoon - Select Scenario for New Game Window]

Compare this to the installation on my old computer. When I open the "Select Scenario for New Game" window on my old computer, it shows the exact scenarios that have been completed. This tells me that the "completed scenario" data is stored elsewhere on the computer:

[image]

What I've tried so far is to move other files and folders from the installation directory on my old computer to my new one.

```
..\steamapps\common\RollerCoaster Tycoon Deluxe\Data

..\steamapps\common\RollerCoaster Tycoon Deluxe\RCTDeluxe_install

..\steamapps\common\RollerCoaster Tycoon Deluxe\Scenarios

..\steamapps\common\RollerCoaster Tycoon Deluxe\Tracks
```

Transferring the files from the above directories has not solved the problem. So this still leaves the original question: where is the completed scenario data stored?

I've done a little research, and the resulting information is mixed:

1. This [Steam forum post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/285310/discussions/0/3113644379507232553/) suggests it's not possible to transfer this data, and that the scenarios must all be completed again from scratch. I find this hard to believe, but I suppose it's possible. The same post also suggests that the "workaround" is to download scenarios off the internet that were saved right before the scenarios were completed. Then, upon loading the scenarios, they will be logged as completed on your new installation.
2. This [Steam forum posts](https://steamcommunity.com/app/285310/discussions/0/520518688947562894/) suggests something about manipulating the system time when restoring saved data, but it doesn't give much detail beyond that.
3. A user in this [GOG forum post](https://www.gog.com/forum/rollercoaster_tycoon_series/how_do_i_transfer_my_userdata_to_new_pc) states the following:

> To transfer scenario progress, you must place the save file for any
> completed parks in the default save game location inside the
> installation folder. These files must be present the first time you
> start the game on a new machine; on the first run, the game checks for
> saves of completed parks in the save game folder, and marks any parks
> it finds as beaten on the main menu.

However, I followed the steps of placing my "Saved Games" data in the appropriate folder before first booting the game, and this did not work for me. It's worth noting that the instructions above are specific to the GOG version, but I would think that due to the age of the game, there shouldn't be any major differences between the GOG and Steam versions, at least as far as how the data is saved.

I would greatly appreciate any comments or discussions on how this data is stored, and how it might be transferred to a new computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more digging, I found a [Web Archive post](https://web.archive.org/web/20131221171850/http://www.rctstationarchive.com/knowledgebase/transfer_scenario_progress.shtml) for an old website called RCT Station. The post confirms that CSS0.DAT is the file where scenario progress is stored, as long as you have the Loopy Landscape pack. All current versions sold on GOG and Steam have the Loopy Landscape pack.

Here are the instructions. I've shortened the instructions from the original post to be more relevent to the GOG and Steam versions, and I've also tested these steps for both GOG and Steam on Windows 11:

1. Install RollerCoaster Tycoon: Deluxe
2. Start the game at least once.
3. Rename the CSS0.DAT that has been created in the DATA directory on your hard disk. Steam version: `..\steamapps\common\RollerCoaster Tycoon Deluxe\Data`. GOG version, if using GOG Galaxy: `C:\Program Files (x86)\GOG Galaxy\Games\RollerCoaster Tycoon Deluxe\Data`
4. Reset the time on your system to 20 December 1998.
5. Copy the old CSS0.DAT that you made into the DATA directory. After copying, ensure that the file is NOT read-only by right-clicking on it and selecting 'Properties'.
6. Start the game up.  If you choose the New Game icon from the title screen, you should see that your progress has been restored.
7. Reset the system date and time to the correct value.

The credit goes to Dave at RCT Station.

Comment: What happens if you don't adjust your system clock?

Comment: @Stevoisiak If you don't adjust your system clock, it doesn't work. I tried all of the steps above without resetting my system clock, and it definitely fails. I don't know what's written in the code that requires that step, but it is required.

Comment: Feel free to self-accept your own answer if you feel the extra information better answers your issue.

Answer (score 2):

[According to Gymnasiast90 on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rct/comments/81hgzk/help_resetting_high_scores/dv43pvs/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=mweb3x&utm_name=mweb3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button), scenario progress is stored in the `data` folder as `CSS0.DAT` or `scores.dat`.

Comment: I can confirm that this is the file for those who have the Loopy Landscape pack. I will add an answer with the instructions I found.